# Slow loading PHP script makes Cloudflare block connections

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cloudflare

I use php-fpm and nginx, I am running a slow script but it's blocking all Cloudflare connections, most likely it's a php-fpm issue but I can't find anything via Google.

If I run the php script (sleep(10)) it will block all other pages until the script has finished. However, I access the server directly and I don't get this problem.

Any ideas?

php-fpm config:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50000
pm.start_servers = 120
pm.min_spare_servers = 90
pm.max_spare_servers = 180
pm.max_requests = 5000
request_slowlog_timeout = 60s
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
catch_workers_output = yes
```

nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  12;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  19000;
}
worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    access_log off;
    etag off;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I'm seeing a LOT of bad issues with Cloud Flare right now. It might not really be your fault. Especially if you are using the free service level.

Comment: You're right that Cloudflare does have its flaws but today was not Cloudflares fault. I forgot I had sessions enabled hidden away inside the php.

Comment: Thank you for calming the waters. I've been through a lot of pain from them recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, it was the session handler causing the problem.

Pro-tip, don't auto-session inside 3 layers of includes!